# Загрузка и обработка файлов на Node.js

Tags: node.js

Необходимо провести с загруженным файлом две операции.

1) Определить, является ли он изображением.

2) Переименовать с сохранением расширения

Используется модуль `formidable`, поэтому код выглядит так:

```
app.post('/test', function(req ,res) {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            //тут все операции с файлом
        });
    });
});
```

Как должно работать: при поступлении файла происходит проверка, изображение ли это. Если изображение, то ему присваивается имя img, а расширение сохраняется. Примеры работы:

`test.png` -> `img.png`

`example.jpg` -> `img.jpg`

`fall.exe` -> ERROR (file is not image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в начало файла

```
var path = require("path"); 
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async"); // npm install async
```

Затем немного измените создание `IncomingForm`

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({keepExtensions: true}); //сохраняем расширения у загруженных файлов
```

Обработка файлов

```
async.parallel(Object.keys(files).map(function(name){
  var file = files[name];
  if(file.type.indexOf("image/") === 0){ //Если файл картинка, т.е. имеет тип image/xxxxxx
     return fs.rename.bind(fs, file.path, path.join(path.dirname(file.path), "img", path.extname(file.path)));  // originalName.png(jpg, etc) -> img.png(jpg, etc)
  }
  else{
    //Not Image!!!
    return function(cb){cb(new Error("Not Image"));};
  }
}), function(err){
  //дальнейшие шаги после переименования картинок
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Comment: Советую так же проверить размер файла:  if( file.type.indexOf("image/") === 0) && file.size > 0 && file.size < 3146000 ){...
 //например 3 мегабайта